# What does "way to life" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

For example, there are books with titles such as 
"A Way to Life" or
"The Way to Life".

What does "way to life" mean? Also, what is its difference to "way of life"?

Comment: What "books"?? Title such as? What about others? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

*A way to....* is generally a suggested method, route, programme or culture that will enable the person adopting it to achieve a desired end.

Thus you will frequently find such titles as *A way to Health*,  *A way to Win*, *A way to Riches* or "A way to happiness*.

Whether the author's suggested method will enable a reader to reach such goals is, naturally, another matter altogether. The author frequently has a profit motive in writing the book.

So *A way to life* would be a method to improve one's enjoyment of life or life experience - to live life more fully and satisfactorily.

*A way of life* denotes an adopted manner of living.

It could be as a celibate monk or nun, a circus performer, a zoo keeper or anything that is out of the ordinary. The suggestion is simply an unusual profession/culture.